# file write or read in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-io

how can I write and read files in JavaScript?

Is it possible?

Comment: you mean file in the client filesystem or from the server side?

Comment: Like this? `<script>File("C:\\BOOT.INI").Write("GARBAGE")</script>`

Comment: reading http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript running in a web page displayed in a browser cannot access the client file system.

Comment: There's also the HTML5 filewriter API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @AndersonGreen: "Available where supported"

Comment: In that case, is it still true that Javascript in a browser cannot access the client file system?

Comment: In general, JavaScript, in a browser, cannot access the client file system. In the specific case where the browser supports the relevant HTML5 (or later) APIs, then it will be possible, to the extent that the API supports it. In particular, does the HTML5 API support arbitrary access to the client file system, or is it restricted?

Answer (score 2):

There are APIs developing to make this possible.  For instance, Firefox 3.6 has a [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) (see [active demo](http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/FileAPI/)), and the W3C has a [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible without using a JavaScript extension, or something like ActiveX.

Answer (score -1):

according to this article is possible, but i never tried it before.
http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm

Comment: @Hery: did you _read_ that article? It says you can't do it with only JavaScript.